# Android- Media player stops when screen orientation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

I am developing app with using the Android media player. The media player stops when screen goes to landscape mode. So, i used

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

inside `<activity>`

Now media player stopping problem is solved, but screen not changes to (layout-land) layout. In both landscape and portrait modes the same landscape layout is appearing. pls guide me

Comment: You need to override `onConfigurationChanged` method in your activity and do the needful to change the layout appropriately.

Comment: Could you pls give me a example code.

Comment: See [Handle configuration changes](https://d.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes) in official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

go to AndroidManifest.xml

and inside `<activity>` tag put the following:

`android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`

that worked for me now media player doesn't stop when changing screen orientation

Comment: Caution! Handling the configuration change yourself can make it much more difficult to use alternative resources, because the system does not automatically apply them for you. This technique should be considered a last resort when you must avoid restarts due to a configuration change and is not recommended for most applications. https://d.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes#HandlingTheChange